# Why my logrotate is not working?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, logrotate

I'm trying to rotate my application's log daily, but for some unknown reason, it's not working. If I debug its logrotate definition, it says that it won't rotate it. However, only when I force its rotation it works..

What am I missing here?

#### logrotate definition (/etc/logrotate.d/application)

```
/tmp/company.0000/application.log {
  daily
  rotate 7
  compress
  copytruncate
  missingok
  extension .log
  dateext
  dateformat _%Y%m%d
  su root valter
  create 440 valter valter
}
```

#### list everything in the folder

```
valter@eniac:~$ ls -ltha /tmp/company.0000/
total 2,8M
drwxrwxrwx 9 root   root    96K Aug 30 17:25 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 valter valter 4,0K Aug 30 17:25 .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 valter valter 2,7M Aug 30 17:00 application.log
```

#### modified the file date

```
valter@eniac:~$ sudo touch -m --date="2016-08-01" /tmp/company.0000/application.log
valter@eniac:~$ ls -ltha /tmp/company.0000/
total 2,8M
drwxrwxrwx 9 root   root    96K Aug 30 17:25 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 valter valter 4,0K Aug 30 17:25 .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 valter valter 2,7M Aug  1 00:00 application.log
```

#### debug logrotate without modified the log itself

```
valter@eniac:~$ sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/application 
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/application
extension is now .log

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /tmp/company.0000/application.log  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 0 and egid to 1000
considering log /tmp/company.0000/application.log
  log does not need rotating
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

#### forcing log to rotate and listing

```
valter@eniac:~$ sudo logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/application 
valter@eniac:~$ ls -ltha /tmp/company.0000/
total 264K
drwxrwxr-x 2 valter valter 4,0K Aug 30 17:26 .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 valter valter    0 Aug 30 17:26 application.log
drwxrwxrwx 9 root   root    96K Aug 30 17:25 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 valter valter 158K Aug  1 00:00 application_20160830.log.gz
```

Comment: Do you have a global `size` option?

Comment: No @MarkPlotnick, is that necessary ? I thought that wouldn't be necessary once I'm saying to rotate daily only.

Comment: It's not required to have a `size` option, but if you do have one, it'll take precedence over `daily`.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/etc/logrotate.d/application` ?  It should be similar to `644`; specifically it should _not_ have any `x` flags set; that can cause `logrotate` to skip the file in some versions.

Comment: My permissions are `644`.

Comment: Note that `logrotate` also saves the state of the logfiles that it watches.  The default location of that is in `/var/lib/logrotate.status`.